# how to stack mulitple div's horizontaly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to stack some div's horizontally, but can't figure out how.
I also need to have the option to stack a child vertically, and I don't know how to do that using Flex.
Example:

```css
.child {border: 1px solid orange}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content 1</div>
  <div class="child">Content 2</div>
  <div class="child">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

[image]
I want the same functionality as ROW and COL in Bootstrap, where you can define

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
```

if the screen is smaller than the MD breakpoint, the div stacks vertical.

Comment: have you ever heard about [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Comment: A `span` would fit your needs.

Comment: `.parent {display: flex}`

Comment: Float them left or change the display to inline-block

Comment: oh I'm sorry I didn't write I'm also considering flex, but I also need that some of t he children can can stack vertically

Comment: `.child {display:inline-block}`

Comment: sorry but that didn't work

Comment: What happend to Content3?

Comment: Content 3 is what I'm looking for, to be able to stack the children horizontally but also be able to specify that a child must be stacked vertically, just like it would without any Flex.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question properly, you can use float.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
</div>

.parent {
  float: left
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

and fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/8opzLqu9/6/

Oops, just re-read the question. Essentially you set the child div as inline-block (as folk have commented). Like so:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content 1</div>
  <div class="child">Content 2</div>
  <div class="child">Content 3</div>
</div>

.parent {
  width: 500px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8opzLqu9/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `span` instead of a `div`:

```
<div>
    <span>Content 1</span>
    <span>Content 2</span>
    <span>Content 3</span>
</div>
```

Or set 'display' to `inline` or `inline-block`, like below:

```
.child {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid orange}

<div>
    <div class="child">Content 1</div>
    <div class="child">Content 2</div>
    <div class="child">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Above is the way to go. You just might need to give specific width to the elements to see it take effect. If that makes sense.

Comment: My code doesn't reflect the changed layout of Content 3.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help.

```css
.child {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  }
  
.child:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content 1</div>
  <div class="child">Content 2</div>
  <div class="child">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapping [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and set the width of the `.child` to 50%. Use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):border-box to include the width of the border into the 50% width of the child.

Now you can set the parent to any width desired, and the children will follow.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content 1</div>
  <div class="child">Content 2</div>
  <div class="child">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that worked, except I don't want to wrap it since I want the children to resize but not create new rows. I'm sure this must be possible. Just like the Row and Col in Bootstrap.